# Typescript isn't able to understand a property is not null for sure

Tags: typescript

```
interface A {
    id?: string
}

interface B {
    id: string
}

function test(a: A, b: A) {
    if (!a.id && !b.id) { return }

    let c: B = {
        id: a.id || b.id
    }
}
```

[Link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20id%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20id%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20if%20(!a.id%20%26%26%20!b.id)%20%7B%20return%20%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20let%20c%3A%20B%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20id%3A%20a.id%20%7C%7C%20b.id%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

The error I get:

> Types of property 'objectId' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How can I go around this? One between `a.id` an `b.id` is defined, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Of course disabling `strickNullChecks` isn't an option.

tsc 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daniel-klischies says, TypeScript's control-flow analysis is not up to the task and you need to help it.  In this case, TypeScript is not trying to apply [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to see that `(!a.id && !b.id)` is the same as `!(a.id || b.id)`.  It would probably be *possible* to implement, but spending compiler time checking for this is probably not worth the added bit of control-flow completeness.

But since *we* know that those are identical, we can help TypeScript by using that identity:

```
function test(a: A, b: A) {
  const id = a.id || b.id;
  if (!id) return;
  let c: B = { id: id };
}
```

This type checks as desired.  Good luck!

Comment: While applying De Morgans laws here would solve the problem, it is not generally possible to validate such constraints in finite time and space. So yes, for this specific scenario it is possible, but in general it is NOT possible.  Satisfiability in first order logic is undecidable in general, that means if you can have some constraint `con` that is unsatisfiable, but no computer will be able to figure this out. Now you do something like `var foo = (con) ? null : "bar"` and it wont be possible to determine if foo will never be null for a computer, although in fact it will always be "bar".

Comment: You're right, of course.  You're stressing the "it can't be done in general" part, while I'm stressing the "it can be done in some specific cases" part.  Since the TypeScript compiler *does* in fact perform some control-flow-based type analysis, as opposed to just giving up, I feel it's worth showing how the OP can make use of this functionality as shown above.

Comment: Oh okay, nevermind then. I wasnt sure if "It would probably be possible to implement" referred to this specific case or all cases in which such checks are required. The amount of control flow analysis that is done is pretty much arbitrary, and might change in the future I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript cannot automatically deduce that at the line where you set your `c` at least one id must be non-null. The reason for this is based on computability theory (i.e. it is just not possible to do this reliably and for all edge-cases).

So you will have to add a typecast manually:

```
let c: B = {
    id: <string>(a.id || b.id)
}
```